# Using list_display in django 1.4.5 effect performance

Tags: django, django-admin

I am struggling at fixing a performance penalty I have on my site on the admin pages of django.

I have a model with 2 foreign keys to other models. Nothing fancy. I am doing the following in my admin.py :

```
class VoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ UserVoteCriteriaInline ]
  list_display = ('user')
  readonly_fields = ('solution','user')
```

and I am registering the admin as followed :

```
admin.site.register(Vote,VoteAdmin)
```

My model have no background processing and I have also delete the **unicode** function just in case.

Now my database now have 20k votes entries. I felt that when getting into the admin it takes a while to load, and now it takes 26 seconds for the query to complete. So I start to debug it.

What I find is that if I remove the list_display the query complete in less then a second. But adding the list_display jump it to 25-30 seconds. It doesn't matter what type I add to the list_display, as long as the list_display exists I have this problem.

Looking at the queries it seems to be totally different then with-out list_display. but I have no clue why and what I can do .

EDIT : I see the when I am not using list_display the quest is a simple select such as :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `main_vote`; args=()
SELECT `main_vote`.`id`, `main_vote`.`user_id`, `main_vote`.`solution_id`, `main_vote`.`text`,
`main_vote`.`wow_factor`, `main_vote`.`vote_factor`, `main_vote`.`score`, 
`main_vote`.`vote_date`, `main_vote`.`active` FROM `main_vote` ORDER BY `main_vote`.`id`
DESC LIMIT 100; args=()
```

But when I am using list_display with only the user on the display it try to resolve ANY inner join and it becomes a HUGE SQL operation.

Maybe it is a known bug on 1.4.5 ?

ANOTHER EDIT : I figured out that if I do :

```
class VoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_select_related = True
```

I am having the same problem just like using the list_display. Is it possible that list_display by default enable the select_related flag ? If that's true, how can I disable it ? I tried to make it false but it doesn't seems to effect anything.

Comment: `list_display` does use `select_related` if there are any foreign key fields in the `list_display`. Unfortunately, the Django admin does not expose a way to control how deep the `select_related` call goes. I've never been able to come up with a way to control this other than writing a custom `ChangeList` class for the admin that has a different implementation of `get_query_set`. If you can live without the related objects in your `list_display` that's a simpler approach.

Comment: Also, the performance hit for `select_related` is not usually that severe. You might want to doublecheck the query to see if there's something you can change about your database design to simplify the join.